# Exploring QEMU/KVM: Performance and Setup Comparison on Windows 11 vs. Linux

Tags: windows, virtualbox, qemu

I have used QEMU/KVM in Fedora, and it was superior in comparison to VirtualBox or the free version of VMWare. Recently, I wanted to dual-boot Linux with Windows, but I couldn't due to battery problems. Does QEMU work well on Windows 11? I know it's primarily made for Linux, but has anyone tested it on Windows, and how does its performance compare to Linux? Is it easy to set up and use? (Because in Fedora, it only takes three lines of command to install and run QEMU).

Comment: I've used QEMU on windows once, about 5 years ago. Worked fine back then.